# Can we get data in aspx.cs page from Angular controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs

I have a project which contains all plain html pages with angularJS and one .aspx page. I need some data in list/json format in my aspx page's code behind from angular controller. Can this be done ? If yes, please guide. 
I'm new to angular, please be kind.

Scenario is I want to download the current html page as pdf. I found jspdf but for some reason it is not working in IE, works in chrome.

So, I am putting a workaround where I can do this with aspx page, I just need data there.

```
//Download PDF
    $scope.PDFDownload = function () {
        window.open('ReportPage.aspx');
        //need to send list/json data to aspx code behind here.
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need some data in list/json format in my aspx page's code behind
>   from angular controller.

If you want to send/receive data to/from ASPX Web Form, you want to use [WebMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx).

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace DemoWebForm
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static string PostJson(string firstName, string lastName)
        {
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                "Hello, " + lastName + ", " + firstName + "!");
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DemoWebForm.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <form id="form1" runat="server" ng-controller="DemoController">
        <pre>{{user}}</pre>
        <button type="button" onclick="ajaxPostData();">Post Data Ajax</button>
        <button type="button" ng-click="ngPostData()">Post Data Angular</button>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ajaxPostData() {
                var user = { firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe" };
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx/postjson") %>',
                    data: JSON.stringify(user),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            }
            var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', [])
                .controller('DemoController', function DemoController($scope, $http) {
                    $scope.user = { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Doe" };

                    $scope.ngPostData = function () {
                        $http.post('<%= ResolveUrl("~/default.aspx/postjson") %>', $scope.user)
                            .then(function (result) {
                                console.log(result.data.d);
                            });
                    }
                });
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Screen shot

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am leaving the office right now but will try it asap and let you know.